# Splitting array into individual string

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, implode

this is a problem I keep running into, and would like to know the best way to do this.

I'm trying to split each value in this array into an individual string,

```
$domainext = array("com","net","edu","uk","au","in","biz","ca","cc","cd","bz","by");
```

Here is how I'm doing it.

```
 foreach ($domainext as $ext){
        $ext = implode(', ', $domainext);

        echo $ext."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

this is the output.
com, net, edu, uk, au, in, biz, ca, cc, cd, bz, by 
(however, there are as many lines as there are array values)

I have tried using explode, and it returns "array" with an error above it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: you dont need `$ext = implode(', ', $domainext);` inside the loop.

Comment: Don't worry about asking basic questions, stack overflow isn't just for advanced questions.

Comment: You don't need that loop.  Just `implode` once

Comment: I think he wants one domain text on each line due to wrapping each one with <br>

Comment: Why a downvote ? i don't think that's fair since he is stating it's a basic question

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$domainext = array("com","net","edu","uk","au","in","biz","ca","cc","cd","bz","by");

print implode("\n", $domainext);
```

This gives:

```
com
net
edu
....
```

Oops... replace the "\n" by a br tag if you are printing to a web page.

```
print implode("<br/>", $domainext);
```

Comment: As seen below, join works too. I believe it is an alias of implode.

Comment: Just FYI.... implode takes an array and converts to a string. explode takes a string and converts it into an array.  The "glue" can be specified for both.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to implode or explode anything :), try this:

```
foreach ($domainext as $ext){
        echo $ext."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output the items in your array on a different row, you cna use join

```
echo join("<br/>",$domainext);
```

As others have said, no loop necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
echo join('<br>', $domainext);
```

will do the job if you want each domain suffix separated with HTML line breaks (the exact required output is unclear from your question). Join is an alias of implode, and preferable from its clearer meaning.